# 'Cannot use import statement outside a module' when importing a local module that imports other stuff

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, package

So, I'm building an api that makes use of a package I already made to manage mongoDB conection, schemas and so on.
When I import my local package (through `npm link package`) it throws a `Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

Here is the code for...

My API attempt:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { bcrypt } from 'bcrypt';
import { AllowMail, User, UserToken } from 'cofradia-data-layer';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor() {}

  async hello() {
    return 'hello';
  }

  async singup(user: {
    name: string;
    tagName: string;
    mail: string;
    bio?: string;
    pic?: string;
    password: string;
  }) {
    //Check if user exists
    let userCheck =
      (await User.findOne({ tagName: user.tagName })) ||
      (await User.findOne({ mail: user.mail }));

    if (userCheck) throw new Error('u-001-01');

    //Check if mail is invited
    let allowMail = await AllowMail.findOne({ mail: user.mail });
    if (!allowMail) throw new Error('u-001-02');

    //Create PW HASH
    let salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    let hash = bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);

    //Create userdata for storage
    let userData = {
      name: user.name,
      tagName: user.tagName,
      mail: user.mail,
      bio: user.bio,
      pic: user.pic,
      pwsalt: salt,
      pwhash: hash,
    };

    //Create obj, save and return
    let userObj = await User.create(userData);
    return await userObj.save();
  }

  async singin(username: string, password: string) {
    //Check if user exists
    let user =
      (await User.findOne({ tagName: username })) ||
      (await User.findOne({ mail: username }));

    if (!user) throw new Error('u-002-01');

    //Check if password match
    let result = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.pwhash);

    if (!result) throw new Error('u-002-02');

    //Create, save and return token
    let tokenObj = await UserToken.create({
      user: user.id,
      token: crypto.randomUUID(),
      isValidStill: 1,
    });
    return await tokenObj.save();
  }
}
```

And the package main.ts file:

```
import mongoose from "./mongoose.driver";
import { User, UserSchema } from "./clases/user/user.model";
import { Follow, FollowSchema } from "./clases/follow/user.model";
import { AllowMail, AllowMailSchema } from "./clases/allowmail/allowmail.model";
import {
  UserToken,
  UserTokenSchema,
  checkUserToken,
} from "./clases/usertoken/usertoken.model";

const onInit = async () => {
  let tokens = await UserToken.find({ isValidStill: 1 });

  for (const token of tokens) {
    token.isValidStill = 0;
    await token.save();
  }

  console.log(`${tokens.length} tokens revoked`);
};

export {
  mongoose,
  User,
  UserSchema,
  Follow,
  FollowSchema,
  AllowMail,
  AllowMailSchema,
  UserToken,
  UserTokenSchema,
  checkUserToken,
};
```

when I run the api it throws:

```
import mongoose from "./mongoose.driver";
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I Already tryed scycling through various sets of configurations both on the package and api, changed stuff on tsconfig.json and package.json